# My code "ignores" multiple correct Displays and chooses the first one It Catches

Tags: c

i've made a code that prints out to me the number with the most divisors from a chosen range and then it lists the divisors , now my problem is that there is a special case upon entering a range which have most than one number with equal number of divisors then the code cuts and prints the closest number to it and ignores all other

for example if i input a range between 5 and 10 it gives me 6 as the number with the max count of divisors but it ignores the 8 and the 10 but i want the code to print them out because they too have the same count of divisors as 6 does , is there anyway i can fix it ?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
void MaxCountDivisors();
void PrintMaxCountDivisors(int Low, int Max);
int main() {
    MaxCountDivisors();
    return 0;
}
void MaxCountDivisors() {
    int Low;
    int High;
    printf("Please insert two numbers. \n");
    scanf("%d",&Low);
scanf("%d",&High);
while (High < Low || Low < 0 || High < 0) {
    printf("You've inserted invalid values, please try again.\n");
    scanf("%d",&Low);
    scanf("%d",&High);
}
PrintMaxCountDivisors(Low, High);
}
void PrintMaxCountDivisors(int Low, int High) {
int i;
int Divisor;
int Count;
int Max = 0;
int MaxNumber;
int Divided;
int j;

for (i = Low; i <= High; i++) {
    Count = 0;

    for (Divisor = 1; Divisor <= i; Divisor++) {

        Divided = (i % Divisor);
        if ((Divided) == 0) {
            Count++;
            if ((Count > Max)) {
                Max = Count;
                MaxNumber = i;
                printf("%d Has maximum divisors. \n", MaxNumber);
                printf("The number of the divisors is: %d", Count);
                for (Divisor = 1; Divisor <= MaxNumber; Divisor++) {

                    if ((MaxNumber % Divisor) == 0)
                        printf("The dividers are: %d \t", Divisor);
                }
                if (Count == Max) {
                    for (j = 1; j <= MaxNumber; j++) {
                        if ((MaxNumber % j) == 0)
                        {
                            printf("%d Have maximum divisors. \n", MaxNumber);
                            printf("The number of the divisors is: %d", Count);
                            for (Divisor = 1; Divisor <= MaxNumber; Divisor++) {

                                if ((MaxNumber % Divisor) == 0)
                                    printf("The dividers are: %d \t", Divisor);
                            }
                        }
                        printf("\n\n");
                    }
                }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use for each number of the interval an array to save its divisors like this:

```
int main()
{
    int n,m,temp;
    printf("give the lower bound of the interval :");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("give the upper bound of the interval :");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    if(n>m)
    {
       temp=n;
       n=m;
       m=temp;
    }
    int c=2;//each integer has at least two divisors: 1 and itself
    for(int i=n;i<=m;i++)
    {int s=0,T[i],p=0;
        for(int j=2;j<=(i/2);j++)
        {
             if(i%j==0)
             {
                s++;
                T[p]=j;
                p++;
             }
        }
        if(s>c)
        {
             printf("\n%d has %d divisors :[1][%d]",i,s+2,i);
             for(int k=0;k<p;k++)
             {
                 printf("[%d]",T[k]);
             }
        }
         c=s;
    }
     printf("\n\n");
 }
```

Example:

input:

n=5,m=10

output:

6 has 4 divisors :[1][6][2][3]

8 has 4 divisors :[1][8][2][4]

10 has 4 divisors :[1][10][2][5]